# Apache2 Permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, permissions, accessibility

I'm running a website on Ubuntu server. I have concerns about security. I checked the server folder permissions (Apache httpd) `/etc/apache2` and it looks like:

[image]

I don't have much experience in this field. Can anyone tell me what to change and how i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the Apache2 service runs under the user `www-data`, so this user must be able to read the files.

As you also need to read this files, my advice is that you change the group of the files and directories to `www-data` and adjust the permissions to "Create and Delete files" for the user, "Access files" for the group and "None" to others.